# How to compute this limit which seems to be e?

Tags: limits

Compute :$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \Bigg(1+\ln\frac{n+1}{n}\Bigg)^n$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: We know that $\ln(\frac {n+1}n)=\ln(1+\frac 1n)\approx \frac 1n$ so the result is not surprising.  Now you just need to justify that the lower order terms do not change the result.

Comment: @RossMillikan sir,Any proof of ln[(n+1)/n] is approximate to 1/n.

Comment: Just consider the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: Can you establish and then use that $$\frac{1}{n+1}\;<\;\ln\frac{n+1}{n}\;<\;\frac 1n\;\;?$$